# Is it possible to publish Power BI dashboard to web?

Tags: powerbi

I have created a Power BI dashboard linked to the report and I am able to publish the power BI report to web. I would like to know if its possible to publish the dashboard, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found what to do about this, the YouTube link below explains it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSAHwE21Buk